# regex for finding files at a specific point in the file structure

Tags: regex

I am trying to match file paths that have a specific file at a certain depth in the file structure using regex, so far i have

`/^([A-Z]:\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(.*?\\)(?!.*\\)(<filename>)$/`

exploded it looks like:

```
/^
([A-Z]:\\)
(.*?\\)
(.*?\\)
(.*?\\)
(.*?\\)
(?!.*\\)
(<filename regex>)
$/
```

the problem that i have is that i cant seem to match a filename without also accepting the whole string.

a few examples of file structure that i dont want to work:

`P:\example folder\example folder - 2\eample folder - 3\Rev 0\Example Folder - 4\example file.pdf`

`P:\example folder\Example Folder - 2\example file.pdf`

versus what i need to match:

`P:\example folder\example folder - 2\eample folder - 3\Rev 0\example file.pdf`

Comment: maybe `[^\\]*` instead of `.*?` otherwise you will match arbitrary depths

Comment: `/^[A-Z]:\\([^\\]+\\){4}(filename)$/`

Comment: thankyou! this was not exactly what i needed but ended up leading me to the correct answer

Comment: Perhaps you can post your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others may also benefit from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am still learning regex but yes as jhnc said I was matching with the incorrect amount of characters causing my regex to fail.

what I needed was to use was a negated set as described by jhnc `[^\\]*` this looks for the escape character backslash and matches anything before it.

Then too find the filename I used the same negated set to search for another backslash to make sure it did not look past the 4 levels of files and then looked for the. and the file extension.

The end result looked like this:

`/^[A-Z]:\\([^\\]+\\){4}([^\\]+)(\.)(\w+)$/`

```
/^
[A-Z]:\\       -- find drive e.g. C:\\
([^\\]+\\){4}  -- find 4 backslashes in the file path
([^\\]+)       -- check if there is another backslash
(\.)           -- find a period
(\w+)          -- find any file extension
$/
```